# Plotting a bar chart with years grouped together

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the fivethirtyeight bechdel dataset, located here https://github.com/rudeboybert/fivethirtyeight, and am attempting to recreate the first plot shown in the article here https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-dollar-and-cents-case-against-hollywoods-exclusion-of-women/. I am having trouble getting the years to group together similarly to how they did in the article.

This is the current code I have:

```
ggplot(data = bechdel, aes(year)) +
geom_histogram(aes(fill = clean_test), binwidth = 5, position = "fill") +
scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("ok", "dubious", "men", "notalk", "nowomen"), 
            values=c("red", "salmon", "lightpink", "dodgerblue", 
"blue")) +
theme_fivethirtyeight()
```

Comment: Help is more likely if you include most of the necessary information here.

Answer (score 0):

I see where you were going with using the histogram geom but this really looks more like a categorical bar chart. Once you take that approach it's easier, after a bit of ugly code to get the correct labels on the year columns.

The bars are stacked in the wrong order on this one, and there needs to be some formatting applied to look like the 538 chart, but I'll leave that for you.

```
library(fivethirtyeight)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(scales)

# Create date range column
bechdel_summary <- bechdel %>%
mutate(date.range = ((year %/% 10)* 10)  + ((year %% 10) %/% 5 * 5)) %>%
mutate(date.range = paste0(date.range," - '",substr(date.range + 5,3,5)))

ggplot(data = bechdel_summary, aes(x = date.range, fill = clean_test)) + 
geom_bar(position = "fill", width = 0.95) +
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
theme_fivethirtyeight()
```

[ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/583ch.png)